# USB2.0 control endpoint stall upon set_configuration request

Tags: usb, driver, intel, osdev

I'm working on xhci controller driver for a proprietary OS. I'm having a problem with enumerating USB2 devices. USB3 devices get enumerated without issues. Here's what my driver does:

1. Attach device and a port status change event is posted.
2. if the event is a USB2 attach, reset the port and wait for it to complete the reset.
3. Send an `enableSlot` command to the controller.
4. if success, send an `AddressDevice` command to the controller.
5. If success, read the device descriptor and get the `maxPacketSize`
6. Update the input context and send an `EvaluateContext` command.
7. If success, read the configuration descriptor.
8. Configure contexts, send `ConfigureEndpoint` command to the controller.
9. If success, send a `SET_CONFIGURATION` request to the device.
10. Device responds with a transfer event with a `success` completion code.

Now, if I attach a USB3 device, all 10 steps complete without issues.
However, if I attach a USB2 device, only the first 9 steps complete and the device responds with a `STALL` on the 10th step.

I have tried more things than I can even list here, including playing with the BSR, sending SET_ADDRESS requests manually, trying other configurations, different devices, sending wrong configurations... They all return a STALL on the **status stage trb**.

Is there any way to know what is causing the usb2 devices to stall? How can I fix this? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: I'd post this question on the OSDEV forum. There is a USB guru there named Ben Lunt who may be able to help you out. https://forum.osdev.org/viewforum.php?f=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I need to set the DIR bit of the status stage trb of the set configuration request to 1. USB3 devices want DIR = 0. I don't know but it works.